# How to capture Redis connection failure on Spring Boot Redis Session implementation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, redis, connection

I have implemented Redis session management using LettuceConnectionFactory on my Spring Boot java application.  I couldn't figure out a way to capture Redis connection failure.  Is there a way to capture the connection failure?

**Spring Boot version:** 2.2.6

**Code:**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpSessionConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHostName;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
    private String redisPassword;

    private @Value("${spring.redis.custom.command.timeout}")
    Duration redisCommandTimeout;

    private @Value("${spring.redis.timeout}")
    Duration socketTimeout;


    @Bean
    LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {

        final SocketOptions socketOptions = SocketOptions.builder().connectTimeout(socketTimeout).build();

        final ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder()
                .socketOptions(socketOptions)
                .build();

        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .commandTimeout(redisCommandTimeout)
                .clientOptions(clientOptions)
                .readFrom(ReadFrom.SLAVE_PREFERRED)
                .build();
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHostName,
                redisPort);

        final LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig,
                clientConfig);
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }     

    @Bean
    public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }
}
```